# Not able to Show/Hide div through selected Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html

In my registration form, users can register by 4 ways given in code. But I don't know how to show and hide  only if users choose Discount or Installment method. This code is not working.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name=register]').click(function(){
        if(this.id=="discount")
        {
            $("#discount").show('slow');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#discount").hide('slow');
        }
        if(this.id=="installment")
        {
            $("#installment").show('slow');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#installment").hide('slow');
        }

});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="reg" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="1">
  <tr><caption>Register</caption>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="register" value="regpaid" />Paid
    <input type="radio" name="register" value="regfree" />Free
    <input type="radio" id="discount" name="register" value="chkdis" onclick="checkdiscount()" />Discount
    <input type="radio" id="installment" name="register" value="chkinst" onclick="checkinstallment()" />Installment
  <div id="discount" style="display:none">
  Paid <input name="paid" type="text" />
  Dsicount <input name="dis" type="text" /></div>
  <div id="installment" style="display:none">
  Paid <input name="amtpaid" type="text" />
  Due <input name="due" type="text" /></div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
```

Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you be more clear on what you want, it is not obvious what you want to achieve

Comment: if user click on Discount or Installment Radio Button then only the content of div should be opened. There are two div, according to the selection - the suitable div should be visible.

Comment: IDs should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to make all your ID's unique then append `'-div'` to the revealable elements so that we can say "*If I select #kittens then show #kittens-div*". E.G:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=register]').click(function(){
        
        //use an attribute selector (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) and hide the two divs
        $("[id$='-div']").hide("slow"); //hide all divs whos id ends in'-div'
        
        //get the id of the clicked element
        var id = $(this).attr("id"); //eg 'discount'
        
        //and show any matched element
        $("#"+id+"-div").show('slow'); //eg '#discount-div'
    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reg" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="1">
  <tr><caption>Register</caption>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="register" value="regpaid" />Paid
    <input type="radio" name="register" value="regfree" />Free
    <input type="radio" id="discount" name="register" value="chkdis" onclick="checkdiscount()" />Discount
    <input type="radio" id="installment" name="register" value="chkinst" onclick="checkinstallment()" />Installment
  <div id="discount-div" style="display:none">
  Paid <input name="paid" type="text" />
  Dsicount <input name="dis" type="text" /></div>
  <div id="installment-div" style="display:none">
  Paid <input name="amtpaid" type="text" />
  Due <input name="due" type="text" /></div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

This is just one of several possible solutions. You could just as easily have a function that reveals an element who's ID matches the selected radio button's value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=register]').click(function(){
        $("#chkdis, #chkinst").hide('slow')
        $("#"+$(this).val()).show('slow');    
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=register]').click(function(){
        $("#chkdis, #chkinst").hide('slow')
        $("#"+$(this).val()).show('slow');    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reg" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="1">
  <tr><caption>Register</caption>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="register" value="regpaid" />Paid
    <input type="radio" name="register" value="regfree" />Free
    <input type="radio" id="discount" name="register" value="chkdis" onclick="checkdiscount()" />Discount
    <input type="radio" id="installment" name="register" value="chkinst" onclick="checkinstallment()" />Installment
  <div id="chkdis" style="display:none">
  Paid <input name="paid" type="text" />
  Dsicount <input name="dis" type="text" /></div>
  <div id="chkinst" style="display:none">
  Paid <input name="amtpaid" type="text" />
  Due <input name="due" type="text" /></div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the same ID for your divs and your radio buttons. Rename the div ID's.

Also include JQuery and properly rename the ids in your javascript

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[name=register]').click(function() {
     if (this.id == "discount") {
       $("#discountDiv").show('slow');
     } else {
       $("#discountDiv").hide('slow');
     }
     if (this.id == "installment") {
       $("#installmentDiv").show('slow');
     } else {
       $("#installmentDiv").hide('slow');
     }

   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="reg" method="post" action="">
    <table width="400" border="1">
      <tr>
        <caption>Register</caption>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="register" value="regpaid" />Paid
          <input type="radio" name="register" value="regfree" />Free
          <input type="radio" id="discount" name="register" value="chkdis" />Discount
          <input type="radio" id="installment" name="register" value="chkinst" />Installment
          <div id="discountDiv" style="display:none">
            Paid
            <input name="paid" type="text" />Dsicount
            <input name="dis" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div id="installmentDiv" style="display:none">
            Paid
            <input name="amtpaid" type="text" />Due
            <input name="due" type="text" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: should i need to do some changes in onclick() in radio button?

Comment: Those radio button onclicks aren't even necessary. It should work without them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
           if($(this).attr('id') == 'discount') {
                $('#discount1').show('slow');  
               $('#installment1').hide('slow'); 
           }
           if($(this).attr('id') == 'installment') {
                $('#installment1').show('slow');  
               $('#discount1').hide('slow'); 
           }
       });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bzrez49/

Here you go!

Comment: Won't hide the divs if the user selects the 'paid' or 'free' radio options

Comment: that's cool code but i also want to hide div if selected Paid or free. How to do that